# audio tag of HTML5 doesnot work consistently in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

```
<audio id="playmysong" src="/media/click.wav" />
<input type="button" onclick="playMe();"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function playMe(){
        var obj = $("playmysong");
        obj.play();
    }
</script>
```

This code works when I click first time. This code still works if I click next time after waiting for around 4-5 seconds from one click to another click. But when I click first and click again within 1 second then it doesn't play sound. This code works fine for Google Chrome have only issue with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery:
Change

```
var obj = $("playmysong");
```

to

```
var obj = $("#playmysong").get(0);
```

Going further, try to use play() and pause():

```
function audioToggle(){
    var obj = $("#playmysong").get(0);
    if(obj.paused) obj.play() else obj.pause();
}
```

Comment: I am using prototype. But this doesn't solve my issue. When I put breakup and track javascript code using firebug. Everytime it makes sound. So I don't know what might be the problem that it doesn't work fine in normal conditions.

Comment: @PRP I can help you look further into this if you can put the code on the web somewhere.

Comment: I changed this code slightly and now I changed

var obj = $("playmysong");

into

var obj = $("playmysong").cloneNode(true);

This resolved my issue. But I am not sure if this is correct option.

To provide some detail on my code 

<audio id="playmysong" style="display:none;" src="/media/click.wav" />
<input type="button" onclick="playMe();" value="Play"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function playMe(){
        var obj = $("playmysong");
        obj.play();
    }
</script>

Length of sound is very short 0.045 second. So basically it need to play at every time I click button.

Answer (score 0):

Once I make clone of the DOM object it worked fine for me

```
var obj = $("playmysong").cloneNode(true);
```

Now it works fine in both FF and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

```
    <html>
  <head>
<style>
```

```
</head>
  <body>
<audio id="audio_with_controls" controls autobuffer >
  <source src="http://www.wav-sounds.com/various/beep.wav" type="audio/wav" />
      Audio tag not supported
</audio>
<!-- some actions from Javascript -->
<button id="play">Play</button>
<button id="play2">Play2</button>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
<button id="duration">Show duration</button>
<div id="duration-log"></div>
<script>
  var song = document.getElementById('audio_with_controls');
  document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click', function() { song.play(); }, false);
  document.getElementById('play2').addEventListener('click', function() { song.play(); }, false);
  document.getElementById('pause').addEventListener('click', function() { song.pause(); }, false);
  document.getElementById('duration').addEventListener('click', function() { document.querySelector('#duration-log').textContent = song.duration; }, false);
</script>
```

You can see this code and run in your browser. You can see how it is different from FF and Chrome. Especially see the slider when sound play is completed. In FF it get stuck in middle and after few second it ends. This is the problem I am having in my application.